# Run Macro with out leaving page

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I have a checkbox that will run this macro when checked.  The check box is in sheet1 and it will hide row 11 in sheet2.  How do I write this code so I do not have to bounce back and forth between sheets?

```
Sub Hide_HeaterTreater_Rows()

  Sheets("NSR Report").Select
  Range("11:11").Select
If Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
  Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
  Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
  End If

Sheets("NSR FORM").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: See this :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select/10718179#10718179

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems kind of odd to be toggling visibility with a checkbox: I would think it would be better to use the checkbox's value to set the visibility...

```
Sub Hide_HeaterTreater_Rows()
  With Sheets("NSR Report").Rows(11).EntireRow  
    .Hidden = Not .Hidden
  End With
End Sub
```

EDIT: multiple rows

```
Sub Hide_HeaterTreater_Rows()
  With Sheets("NSR Report").Range("11:11,24:24").EntireRow  
    .Hidden = Not .Hidden
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked great thank you!  Could you help me understand your explination above?

Comment: Also, how would you write it so that you can hid multiple rows with out getting an error code.  For example rows 14 and 24?

Comment: It sets the Hidden property to the opposite of its current value (`Not False` = True, `Not True` = False)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Hide_HeaterTreater_Rows()
    Sheets("NSR Report").Rows(11).EntireRow.Hidden = Not Sheets("NSR Report").Rows(11).EntireRow.Hidden
End Sub
```

But I *think* you may want to use

```
Sub Hide_HeaterTreater_Rows()
    Sheets("NSR Report").Rows(11).EntireRow.Hidden = Sheets("NSR FORM").Shapes("CheckBox1").Value
End Sub
```